# Exception while making a POST using curl command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sh

I am working on a bash shell script that makes a POST API call to github to update a pull request status through curl command, below is the script I am using

```
export scan_status=''
export status_description=''
if[ "$(param.status)" == "Succeeded" ]; then
      scan_status="success"
      status_description="scan successful"
elif[ "$(param.status)" == "Failed" ]; then
      scan_status="failure"
      status_description="scan failed"
else
     scan_status="pending"
     status_description="scan pending"
fi

_HTTP_STATUS=$(
            curl --silent --show-error --insecure \
                --connect-timeout 20 --retry 5 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 \
                --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
                --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                --header 'User-Agent: TektonCD, the peaceful cat' \
                --header 'Authorization: token '${GITHUB_TOKEN} \
                --output ${_OUT_DATA} \
                --write-out "%{http_code}\n" \
                --data '{"state":"${scan_status}","target_url":"","description":"${status_description}","context":"Checkmarx/$(params.datasource)"}' \
                --request POST \
                --url "$PR_STATUS_URL" | head -1
        )

        echo "status:${_HTTP_STATUS}"
```

When I hit this through script I am getting 422 error on debugging it, I noticed that the parameters scan_status,status_description in data section are being passed as "${scan_status}" & "${status_description}" rather their values.

I have tried passing them without double quotes, wrapping in single quotes, without curly brackets but none of them worked for me.

Can someone please help me to fix this

Comment: That's because they are embedded in single-quoted strings. You should be using `jq` to generate the JSON, not building it by hand using parameter interpolation.

Comment: _here doc_ can handle this as a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this line

```
--data '{"state":"${scan_status}","target_url":"","description":"${status_description}","context":"Checkmarx/$(params.datasource)"}' \
```

to

```
--data "{\"state\":\"${scan_status}\",\"target_url\":\"\",\"description\":\"${status_description}\",\"context\":\"Checkmarx/$(params.datasource)\"}" \
```

Note:

- Values under single quotes doesn't get resolved in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Using *here doc*, no need to quote anything in your `JSON`:

```
 curl --silent --show-error --insecure \
     --connect-timeout 20 --retry 5 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 \
     --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --header 'User-Agent: TektonCD, the peaceful cat' \
     --header 'Authorization: token "${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
     --output "${_OUT_DATA}" \
     --write-out "%{http_code}\n" \
     --url "$PR_STATUS_URL"
     --data "@/dev/stdin"<<EOF
{"state":"${scan_status}","target_url":"","description":"${status_description}","context":"Checkmarx/$(params.datasource)"}
EOF
```

And [don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)